# Return value to main from inside object

Tags: c++, object, error-handling

In my main() I am creating objects that have error checking in the constructor.
If an error occurs I want to return an error code from main() to quit the program.

Should I use a callback to return an error code in main() or should I not put error checking in the constructor; move it to a member function that can return an error code to main()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `throw` for that:

```
struct C
{
    C() {throw std::runtime_error("for the example");}
};


int main()
{
    try
    {
        C c;

        // Do normal stuff (that never happen due to throw)
        return 0;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```